# Ubuntu 17.10 - what is a default window manager?

Tags: window-manager, gnome-shell

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 which uses Gnome Shell 3.24.2. The following commands:

```
wmctrl -m
```

shows an active window manager and I get: Gnome Shell

I have read that Gnome 3 uses Mutter Window Manager, so what is going on ? There is no Mutter process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GNOME Shell does not use a separate window manager process](https://blog.fishsoup.net/2008/10/22/implementing-the-next-gnome-shell/):

> **One Process**. The first thing to note is that the ideas don’t naturally split into “window manager” and “panel”. The “Activities”
>   view combines showing the windows that are currently open with
>   launchers for existing applications. It would be possible to add
>   complex API’s to the window manager to allow putting extra things into
>   its scene graph. But it is going to be far easier to simply work in a
>   single process with clean internal programming interfaces.

The window manager is still [Mutter](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Technology).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
update-alternatives --display x-window-manager
```

to find out what wm your Ubuntu is using, or:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/ | grep -i window
```

Comment: It shows /usr/bin/mutter, but there is no such process, how to find a window manager pid ?