# no caps lock indicator on login screen 17.10

Tags: 17.10, capslock

On the login screen for ubuntu 17.04 it used to have a really nice caps lock indicator right next to the password box. In 17.10 this appears to have disappeared.

Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: Which Window Manager are you currently using (GDM3, sddm, lightdm, etc.)?

Comment: This hack is working for me.  >>  https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdm/+bug/1727466/comments/1

Comment: @Omari just vanilla installed Gnome

Comment: It appears that you are speaking of the desktop environment (DE) but the use of indicators on the login screen depends of the Window Manager that you are using. Which Package Manager do you use to install your programs?

Comment: Appears to be /usr/bin/mutter as per instructions on https://askubuntu.com/questions/935574/ubuntu-17-10-what-is-a-default-window-manager